# How to get a list of classes and functions from a python file without importing it

Tags: python, class, python-import

I have a python file with some classes and functions defined in it:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, an_arg, a_default_arg=None):
        pass

def doStuff(an_other_arg, an_other_default_arg=None):
    pass
```

And I want to get a list of all classes and functions in this file. (their names and parameter definitions are enough)

Now, I do know you can do this with `__import__(module_descriptor)` and `inspect`, but this is not an option as the file I'm scanning is from an untrusted source.

My first reaction was to try and create a safe environment to import them, but this seems impossible according to other stackoverflow-questions.

Comment: 1. you mean "functions", not "executables" 2. Using regex for this seems to be quite easy. Just open the file as you normally would and parse it.

Comment: no, I specifically mean executables as a function wrapped by a wrapper is most often not a function anymore. But I'll change it for clarity. Wouldn't a regex be inappropriate for parsing a programming language, however limited this parsing may be?

Comment: Look at this regex for example: https://regex101.com/r/YPbNcz/1  It can most probably be simplified but it seems like a good place to start. Make sure to use single-line mode so `.` will match line breaks.

Comment: I see some problems with using such regexes: 1) they will most often also return functions and classes defined in multiline comments (single line comments are easily fixable), 2) they cannot detect that some functions are redefined in the same file with another variable type.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use the [ast](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ast.html) module to parse the source file, without actually executing any code. Then you can traverse the node tree to get the function and class names/parameters.

```
import ast

def show_info(functionNode):
    print("Function name:", functionNode.name)
    print("Args:")
    for arg in functionNode.args.args:
        #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        print("\tParameter name:", arg.arg)


filename = "untrusted.py"
with open(filename) as file:
    node = ast.parse(file.read())

functions = [n for n in node.body if isinstance(n, ast.FunctionDef)]
classes = [n for n in node.body if isinstance(n, ast.ClassDef)]

for function in functions:
    show_info(function)

for class_ in classes:
    print("Class name:", class_.name)
    methods = [n for n in class_.body if isinstance(n, ast.FunctionDef)]
    for method in methods:
        show_info(method)
```

Result:

```
Function name: doStuff
Args:
        Parameter name: an_other_arg
        Parameter name: an_other_default_arg
Class name: A
Function name: __init__
Args:
        Parameter name: self
        Parameter name: an_arg
        Parameter name: a_default_arg
```

Comment: This solution is incomplete and will miss `async` function definitions as well as nested functions or classes. I posted a revised version of this solution below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67840804/577829

Answer (score 3):

The accepted solution is incomplete. Consider the following file:

```
def regular_function():
    def nested_function():
        pass

async def async_function():
    pass
```

The accepted solution will only print:

```
Function name: regular_function
Args:
```

To get all functions, we need to make two changes:

1. Walk the entire AST, rather than just top level nodes
2. Handle `async` functions as well as regular functions

Here is the corrected code, for finding functions:

```
import ast

from pathlib import Path

parsed_ast = ast.parse(Path(__file__).read_text())

functions = [
    node
    for node in ast.walk(parsed_ast)
    if isinstance(node, (ast.FunctionDef, ast.AsyncFunctionDef))
]

for function in functions:
    print(f"Function name: {function.name}")
    print(f"Args: {', '.join([arg.arg for arg in function.args.args])}")
```

Note that this is pushing up against the bounds of what an AST walk should be used for. For anything more complicated, consider using [`NodeVisitor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.NodeVisitor)

Answer (score 1):

NOTHING short of actually executing the file can give you a 100% accurate answer to this question.  There are just too many ways in Python to dynamically affect the namespace: importing names from elsewhere, conditionally executing definitions, manipulating the namespace directly by modifying its `__dict__`, etc.

If you can live with only the static definitions, Python's built-in `ast` (Abstract Syntax Tree) module is probably the simplest solution.  You can safely compile the file to an AST, then walk its top level looking for `def` and `class` statements.  (In the case of classes, you'd then walk the class body looking for a `def __init__`.  Don't forget the possibility that a class has no `__init__` of its own, but just inherits one from a superclass!)