# getmembers() for a module with functions inside --> if _ _name_ _ == '_ _main_ _' :

Tags: python

- getmembers() to collect function names inside if `__name__ == '__main__':`
- It works without the above if statement but then the test script will initialize at import which will have other issues that cannot be avoided. but it does return all the module function names properly

`test_oauth.py`

```py
class Tokens():
    ## create access token based on data collected from POST request

if _ _name_ _ == '_ _main_ _':

    access_tokens = Tokens()

   def test_create_client_access_token_structure():
         # ...
    
  def test_access_token_two_hour_expiry_time():
        # ...
```

`collect_test_names.py`

```
from inspect import getmembers, isfunction

def test_names_collector(tests = None):

    functions_names_list = [o[0] for o in getmembers(tests) if isfunction(o[1])]
    test_names_list = [x for x in functions_names_list if x.startswith("test_")]

    return test_names_list

#EXAMPLE and PROBLEM/GOAL
 import test_oauth.py as tests
 test_names_list = test_names_collector(tests=tests)
```

Comment: Nothing under `if _ name _ == '_ main _':` will work if you import that file from another one. Please explain what you are trying to do in more details ?

Comment: @PCM I was trying to import the module function names into another file. Initially did not have that if condition but added it b/c the tests were initializing when importing to collect function names. I do not want to run the scripts, just collect function names. Is there another way?

Comment: got it working by modifying this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44698193/how-to-get-a-list-of-classes-and-functions-from-a-python-file-without-importing