# python import error caused by other class in the same file

Tags: python-3.x, class, import, attributes

b.py

```
class B:
    b = "b"

class BB:
    bb = "d" + 1
```

Then I got

```
>>> from b import B
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/xuting/work/test/class_attr_test/b.py", line 4, in <module>
    class BB:
  File "/home/xuting/work/test/class_attr_test/b.py", line 5, in BB
    bb = "d" + 1
TypeError: must be str, not int
```

How should avoid this if I only want to import **class B**, regardless of whether **class BB** is
legal or not?

**Edit**

In Fact, I'm looking for some code like:

```
try:
    from b import B
except Exception:
    pass

try:
    from b import BB
except Exception:
    pass

print(B.b)  # expect to print "b"
print(BB.b)  # expect raising an exception
```

But as python define all classes while importing, `print(B.b)` raises `NameError: name 'B0' is not defined` instead of `b`.

If change `b.y` to code below:

```
try:
    class B0:
        b = 1
except Exception:
    pass

try:
    class B1:
        b = "d" + 1
except Exception:
    pass

try:
    class B2:
        b = 3
except Exception:
    pass
```

It works, but code seems quite weird.

And to @blhsing answer, I say it's a litte complicated than I expected because it treat `b.py` as a text file, not a python module. But it do seems a good idea to deal a broken python file with model `ast`, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44698193/how-to-get-a-list-of-classes-and-functions-from-a-python-file-without-importing)  may provide more detail.

Comment: Note that there can be code further down in the module which modified `class B` further. It's not always the case that the entire class is defined within the class block (although that is usually the case).

Comment: "I say it's a litte complicated than I expected because it treat b.py as a text file, not a python module." Huh? A Python module *is* a text file parsed and executed as Python code, which is what the built-in `import` does, and what both of my two answers do.

Comment: "...and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44698193/how-to-get-a-list-of-classes-and-functions-from-a-python-file-without-importing) may provide more detail." How? All that answer does is to print attributes of some nodes, while your question demands an actual class object as a result.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the module source into an AST with `ast.parse`, then use `ast.walk` to find a `ClassDef` node whose `name` is `B`, create a new `ast.Module` node with it, compile it and execute it to load `B` into a dict of namespace, so that the rest of the code in the module won't be executed:

```
import ast

with open('b.py') as file:
    for node in ast.walk(ast.parse(file.read())):
        if isinstance(node, ast.ClassDef) and node.name == 'B':
            module = ast.Module(body=[node], type_ignores=[])
            ast.fix_missing_locations(module)
            namespace = {}
            exec(compile(module, filename='', mode='exec'), namespace)
            B = namespace['B']
            break

print(B)
print(B.b)
```

This outputs:

```
<class 'B'>
b
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/ArcticSupportiveScales

Comment: Glad to see there is still a solution here. But It's a little more complicated than I expected， especially when I've got a lot of classes in b.py.  it seems that it's not a good practice to mix classes with complicate attributes together in one file.

Comment: Not sure what kind of a simple solution you were expecting since your code does not follow Python's rules in the first place, and asking to work around the rules is always going to require some sort of a hacky solution. Nevertheless, I just added a "simpler" answer if it can be assumed that `B` is always defined before the module produces an error. If that assumption cannot be made, then this answer is what I believe the most robust workaround you can get.

Comment: Also, why worry about "complicated" code if it actually works? You can store that "complicated" code as a function in a separate module and never have to look at it again if you don't want to be bothered by how "complicated" it looks.

Comment: This (as well as your other answer) only works if the class BB doesn't have some syntax error, which I don't think follows from "_regardless of whether class BB is legal or not_".

Comment: @wim I don't think syntax error is part of the OP's use case since his aim is to "mix classes with complicate attributes together in one file". Syntax error simply means the input is not valid Python code to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

If the class `B` you want to import is always defined before the module `b` raises an exception just like how it is in your question, then a simpler approach would be to execute it in a `try` block, ignore the error with an empty error handler, and retrieve the class `B` that's already defined before the exception from the resulting namespace:

```
from textwrap import indent

with open('b.py') as file:
    namespace = {}
    exec(f'''
try:
{indent(file.read(), ' ')}
except:
    pass
''', namespace)
    B = namespace['B']

print(B)
print(B.b)
```

This outputs:

```
<class 'B'>
b
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/LightgreenFloralwhiteInstruction